# Replace Multiple words in MSWord using Powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use powershell to replace multiple lines in a word document without having to save and close after every change. right now I have:

```
 $objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
    function findAndReplace
    {
        $objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\temp\test.docx")
        $objWord.Visible = $false
        $objSelection = $objWord.Selection
        $a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($FindText, $false, $true, $False, $False, $False, $true, 1, $False, $ReplaceWith)
        $objDoc.Save()
        $objDoc.close()

    }

    ############DEVICE DETAILS#############
    $FindText = "USERID"
    $ReplaceWith = $AssociateIDnum
    findAndReplace
    $FindText = "CONTACTNUMBER"
    $ReplaceWith = $Phone
    findAndReplace
```

Using this, I made the function that runs those commands, and I change the $findtext and $replacetext on each instance of a new word, then run the function each time.

With this method, the Word Doc opens and closes nearly 25 times to write each new word replacement.

Is there a way I can make a function or loop to make it change the $findtext 
and $replacewith variable each time?

I am relatively new to powershell but I have been learning some of it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a list of objects as a parameter to the function, something like that :

```
$objWord = New-Object -comobject Word.Application  
    function findAndReplace ($todoObjs)
    {
        $objDoc = $objWord.Documents.Open("C:\temp\test.docx")
        $objWord.Visible = $false
        $objSelection = $objWord.Selection
        foreach ($todoObj in $todoObjs)
        {
          $a = $objSelection.Find.Execute($($todoObj.FIND), $false, $true, $False, $False, $False, $true, 1, $False, $($todoObj.REPLACE))
        }
        $objDoc.Save()
        $objDoc.close()

    }

    ############DEVICE DETAILS#############
$todo = @"
FIND,REPLACE
toto,titi
tutu,tata
"@

$todoObjs = ConvertFrom-Csv $todo
findAndReplace $todoObjs
```

Comment: What are the toto,titi? are those the variables?

Comment: 'toto', will be replace by 'titi' and 'tutu' will be repace by 'tata' an array of findtext replacetext.